# Updating Power Query Source

Tags: excel

I have a 'Master' sheet that are made up of multiple sheets within the same workbook. I have combined the data from all the sheets to the 'Master' sheet using Power Query. However, I have to repeat a couple of steps(create connection, update source, etc) to include any newly created sheet into the 'Master' sheet.
I am looking at options to automate this process using VBA. Not sure how to start. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean all sheets are in the same workbook?
What do you mean appending using Power Query?
I think you need to  make  question  clear

Comment: Yes, it is within the same workbook. What I meant from that is, I combined the data from other sheets into a single Master sheet.

Comment: I have managed to solve by adding blank new queries.
=Excel.CurrentWorkbook()
Using that, I filtered the tables that I would like to appear in my master sheet

Comment: @raddy, I'm looking to do something similar but I'm not understanding your solution - could you explain your process? Thanks!