# Excel: Dynamically add tables to Power Query merge sources

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure if this is possible but here's the deal:

I've got several tables in individual sheets containing inventory lists, and I've got another sheet with a table that consolidates them based on certain criteria.

The issue is that if I create a new category of inventory, I create a new tab with its own inventory list, but in order to include that inventory in the consolidation table, I have to create a new connection from the new table, and then go into the Power Query Editor for the consolidation table and add the new table into the `Source = Table.Combine({table1, table2, table3, table4})` line.

So essentially I'm wondering if there's some kind of edit I can make to the `Source` line that would automatically update the query sources if we add/subtract sheets. Even if I could use a range there, we could add sheet names to a list each time we add one, that'd work. Basically anything that would be easier than changing code in Power Query. If the only way would be to somehow create a VBA macro and a button that updates the query, that'd be fine too, but any resources you know of that I could look at would be appreciated, since I only have minimal VBA experience.

The closest source I can find about this is: [Updating Power Query Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521325/updating-power-query-source), but the solution sounds somewhat hacky and I'm wondering if there's something cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new, blank query and paste the following into it:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()
in
    Source
```

This will show you a list of all the tables in the current workbook. You can now filter on the tables you want to combine. If you use a naming convention for the tables, you can easily create a filter for tables that start with a specific text, for example "inv".

Then expand the tables and delete the column with the table names. That brings the M to

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "inv")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"data1", "data2"}, {"data1", "data2"})
in
    #"Expanded Content"
```

Add more sheets and more tables that follow that naming convention, and you just need to refresh the query.